# Two sites on the same ip in nginx config

Tags: nginx

I have a server and ip address, without domain. I need to place two projects on the same ip address, one is /api, another - /front.

So it should be like 123.123.123.123/api, 123.123.123.123/front

Here is what I tried to do without success (it says "welcome to nginx" when I visit /front and 404 when I visit /api):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location /api {
        root /var/www/api/pubic;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ /api/.+\.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }

    location /front {
        root /var/www/front/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is somewhat obvious, but I don't know much about nginx configuration, just tried an example from SO.

I use Laravel for /api, and VueJS for /front if it matters.

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block

Comment: What should `/index.html` return? Currently its pointing to the Welcome page! If you meant `/front/index.html` you need to put that at the end of the `try_files` statement. Where are your files located? `/var/www/front/dist/...` or `/var/www/front/dist/front/...`? Your configuration currently assumes the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your issue is the `root` directive in your configuration.

```
location /api {
    root /var/www/api/pubic;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Here, when you try to load http://123.123.123.123/api, nginx loads `/var/www/api/pubic/api/index.php`. That is, nginx appends the directory in `location` directive to `root` when looking up the resource.

If you want to load `/var/www/api/pubic/index.php`, you need to use `alias /var/www/api/pubic`.